# Add active class to the currently selected category archive page in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, liquid, jekyll-paginator

I am using [category-archive plugin](https://github.com/shigeya/jekyll-category-archive-plugin) for my Jekyll project. I want to have a category list menu for each category archive page so the user can navigate between different category archives. I would like to add class="active" to the category list link for the category archive page currently viewed. I have something similar going for the site navigation by comparing the page.url to navitem.url the difference is that for the site nav i specify the list of navitem.urls in config.yml and for the category archive the list of category names is generated based on the categories specified in the post itself, and i am having trouble using the {{ category | first }} variable within the {% if %} operator so i could either check for "==" or "contains"

This is what i have at the moment but it doesn't seem to work

```
<ul class="product-categories">
{% for category in site.categories %}
  {% if page.url == {{ category | first }} %}
    {% assign class = "active" %}
  {% else %}
    {% assign class = "" %}
  {% endif %}
<li>
  <a href="/{{ category | first }}/" class="{{ class }}">{{ category | first }}</a>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Please help  =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class liquid variable is inside the for loop so when you use it outside the scope is empty, also it should be "contains" instead of == because the path contains more characters that won't be present in the category of.

```
<ul class="product-categories"> 
{% assign class = "" %}
{% for category in site.categories %}
{% assign cat=category|first %} 
{% if page.url contains cat %}
 {% assign class = "active" %} 
{% endif %} 
<li> 
<a href="/{{ category | first }}/" class="{{ class }}">{{ category | first }}</a>
 </li> 
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue I am afraid. Unexpected character { in "page.url contains {{ category | first }}" in /_layouts/category_archive.html is the warning i get, no class active is added to current page link. it seems its unable to read {{ category | first }} inside an operator or maybe because contains requires a string? could i convert this to a string?

Comment: @ntnlbd my bad, that should go outside the `if` statement: `{% assign cat=category|first %} then {% if page.url contains cat %} ..`

Comment: legend this has worked! `{% for category in site.categories %}
      {% assign cat = category | first %}
      {% if page.url contains cat %}
        {% assign class = "active" %}
      {% else %}
        {% assign class = "" %}
      {% endif %}
      <li>
        <a href="/{{ category | first }}/" class="{{ class }}">{{ category | first }}</a>
      </li>
    {% endfor %}`